# How do I add new annotations to an MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone

I finally found how to add pins to my image.I will use Mkannotationview and set its image property.But I don't know how to add an (more) annotation(s) to it.

Answer (score 1):

To add annotations:

- get the array of annotations from the map view
- make a mutable copy
- add any new annotations
- set the annotations for the map view to the modified array

Comment: Ok. You say I should get the array of annotations from the map view. But I meant annotationView not map view. I thought I could use MKAnnotationView as it has an Image propery. But MKMapView, as I know, displays maps only.If I use map view instead then how will I display my custom images?

Comment: MKAnnotationView isn't what you seem to think -- it's job is to visually represent a single annotation on a MKMapView. It doesn't let you draw annotations atop the image of your choice; it lets you use the image of your choice to identify a spot on a map. Look at a subclass, MKPinAnnotationView, for an example... it's the class that draws the usual pin images on a map.